# Different controllers in same test

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, integration-testing, junit5, spring-test

I'm writing a integration test as below, and i want to use a BlueResource to do not use the BlueService in this test, the BlueResource has the rest that calls the BlueService method, but i dont want to create another standaloneSetup just for that new controller. Any good ideias to do that? is possibly to initiate a setup to use more than one resources? or all my application controllers ?

```
@DisplayName("IT of GreenResource")
@SpringBootTest(classes = ColorsApp.class)
public class GreenResourceIntTest {

     private MockMvc restMockMvc;

     @Autowired
     private ExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator;

     @Autowired
     private MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jacksonMessageConverter;

     @Autowired
     private PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableArgumentResolver;

     @Autowired
     private GreenService service;

     @Autowired
     private BlueService blueService;

     private GreenResource resource;

     private static final String RESOURCE = "green";

     private static final String API = "/api/";

     @BeforeEach
     @DisplayName("Running setup...")
     void setUp() {
        resource = new GreenResource(service);

        this.restMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(resource)
            .setCustomArgumentResolvers(pageableArgumentResolver)
            .setControllerAdvice(exceptionTranslator)
            .setMessageConverters(jacksonMessageConverter, new ResourceHttpMessageConverter()).build();
}

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Running getAllGreen")
    @Transactional
    void getAllGreen() throws Exception {
        blueService.rush("1");

        restMockMvc.perform(post(API + RESOURCE + "/filter").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(new GreenFilter()))).andExpect(status().isOk());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set @MockBean instead of  @Autowired for

```
private BlueService blueService
```

after that all methods in blueService would return null, if you want some specific in response, you can write

```
Mockito.when(blueService.method()).thanReturn(XXX)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's an approach, but it's not the answer I'm looking for